# PythonでHTMLメール用にCSSをインラインにする方法

Tags: python, css

Python2.7を使っています。

HTML HEAD内のCSSファイルやStyle定義を、BODY内のタグにStyleとして埋め込みたい。変換してくれるモジュールを探しています。

変換前

```
<html><head><style>h1{font-size:20px;}</style></head>
<body><h1>タイトル</h1><div>文章</div>
```

変換後

```
<html><head></head>
<body><h1 style="font-size:20px">タイトル</h1><div>文章</div>
```

Pythonでこのよな処理が可能なモジュールなどはありませんか？
HTMLメールを出す際に必要となっています。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[inlinestyler](http://inlinestyler.torchboxapps.com/) を使うと出来る様です。

**BEFORE**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Example</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://inlinestyler.torchboxapps.com/static/css/example.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <style type="text/css">
            h1{
                color:yellow
            }
        </style>
        <h1>An example title</h1>
        <p>Paragraph 1</p>
        <p class="p2">Paragraph 2</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

**AFTER**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
        <h1 style="color: yellow">An example title</h1>
        <p style="margin: 0;padding: 0 0 10px 0">Paragraph 1</p>
        <p class="p2" style="margin: 0;padding: 0 0 10px 0">Paragraph 2</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: こちらを採用させていただきました。
簡単に実装できました。
情報有り難うございます。

Answer (score 4):

メール送信時の成形目的用には、 [`premailer`](https://github.com/peterbe/premailer) パッケージがよさそう。

#### premailer: インストール

```bsh
$ pip install premailer
```

もしくは、

```bsh
$ wget "https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/premailer/premailer-2.8.1.tar.gz"^
$ tar xvfz premailer-2.8.1.tar.gz
$ cd premailer-2.8.1/
$ sudo python setup.py install
```

#### premailer: 使用例

*サンプルコード*

```py
from premailer import transform

html = u"""<html>
<head>
<style>h1{font-size:20px;}</style>
</head>
<body><h1>タイトル</h1><div>文章</div>
</body>
</html>"""

packed_html = transform(html)
print packed_html
```

*Output:*

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1 style="font-size:20px">タイトル</h1>
<div>文章</div>
</body>
</html>
```

ユニコードの扱いに注意。

Comment: premailerオススメですね。サーバー一台で１日２百万通送信するのに使っています。仕組み上文法的に正しく書かれたHTMLでないとインライン化できないので、jinja2などのテンプレートをインライン化するのは困難でした（制限付きなら不可能ではありませんが）。つまりjinja2のテンプレートレンダリングしてHTMLにしてからtransform(html)が必要ということになります。